# How to check if a 3rd API create a new thread for c/c++ program in linux?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, gdb

Just want to ask is there any method to check if a 3rd API will create a new thread for c/c++ program in linux? As following, assume do_something_API is a 3rd API and we don't know the implementation, then how to know if the funciton will create a new thread? Use gdb or other tools?

```
int main() {
  ...
  //call 3rd party API
  do_something_API();
  ...
}
```

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to enumerate all threads in the currently running process (which means you can count them). Do that before and after and check if there's a difference. And of course, check the documentation! And contact the authors of the third-party library!

Comment: attaching a debugger will also work

Answer (score 1):

> how to know if the funciton will create a new thread?

Just stop at `do_something_API()` line in `main` function in gdb and use `next` command once to execute `do_something_API()` function. If that function creates any new threads, you will see messages from gdb like:

```
[New Thread 0x41e02940 (LWP 25582)]
```

See [in documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads.html):

> Whenever GDB detects a new thread in your program, it displays the
>   target system’s identification for the thread with a message in the
>   form ‘[New systag]’, where systag is a thread identifier whose form
>   varies depending on the particular system. For example, on GNU/Linux,
>   you might see
>
> [New Thread 0x41e02940 (LWP 25582)]

Answer (score 1):

> how to know if the funciton will create a new thread?

1. You may have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you actually trying to achieve?
2. Read the documentation or ask 3rd party developer. If they promise to *never* create threads, then that's the answer. Otherwise, assume that they may (if not in the current version, then in the next one).
3. You can run `nm libsomething.{a,so} | grep pthread_create` and `strings libsomething.{a,so} | grep pthread_create`. If both commands produce no output, you can be pretty sure that the *current* version of the library will not create new threads.
4. If you run the test program under GDB, and `next` over the `do_something_API()` call, GDB will report new thread creation with messages similar to `[New thread ...]`. If you don't see such messages, no new thread was created.

   You could also set a breakpoint on `pthread_create`, or use `info thread` before and after the call.

   Note: if no new threads are created, this is a very *weak* indicator: `do_something_API()` may decide whether or not to create new threads depending on runtime environment (e.g. an environment variable, or current directory, or time of day), and so the next time you run the test the answer may change.

Answer (score 0):

you can try running your code in gdb and use "info threads" to see the all running threads within your program.

or you can also check using /proc/